# Trying to hit Twitter REST API from my react client app. Currently facing the trouble of CORS when running the app locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

The tech stack I am using is Webpack, Reactjs, Nodejs and Heroku.
I have set the application in Twitter and retrieved Consumer key, secret, access token and access token secret. I have tried using various node modules such as request,oauth,oauth1.1 and twit but had no success. I have ran in the problem displayed in the screenshot below:

[CORS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rn2yI.png)

Also my webdev config file looks like this:
var config = {
    entry: './main.js',

```
output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'index.js',
},
devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 8080,
    headers: {
        "X-Custom-Header": "yes",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    },
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',

            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            },

        },
        { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },

    ]
},
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.js', '.jsx']
},
node: {
    console: true,
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
},
noParse: /node_modules\/json-schema\/lib\/validate\.js/
```

};

module.exports = config;
And the code using oauth is:

```
   var oauth = new OAuth.OAuth(
        'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
        'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
        CONSUMER_KEY,
        CONSUMER_SECRET,
        '1.0A',
        null,
        'HMAC-SHA1'
    );
    oauth.get(
        'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=1',
        ACCESS_TOKEN, //test user token
        ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, //test user secret
        function (e, data, res) {
            if (e) console.error(e);
            console.log(data);
        });
    return (
        <div>FU{this.state.trends}</div>
    )
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I have tried most of the suggestions posted online but failed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the twitter API intentionally [does not support CORS](https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Twitters-API-support-CORS). It looks like the best workaround currently is either to run your own proxy server which makes twitter requests on your behalf (and you enable CORS on that), or if you don't want to support a backend service using JSONP is an appropriate workaround. Here's a [brief tutorial](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/Fetching-Cross-Domain-JSON-Tweets-with-JavaScript-and-JSONP) on that technique.